# NGINX is not found (20: Not a directory)

Tags: linux, nginx, debian, web-server, http-status-code-404

When I try to access a file which is named "file" I got the Error 404 - file not found.

I checked on the Server if it exists. Yes it does exist.

I checked if the file is owned by the webuser. Yes it is.

I checked the correct permission. 775 should work, so yes.

The problem is, that the file isn't treated as file. Nginx thinks it is a folder and searches for an index.html file.

```
2017/09/14 11:26:50 [error] 15085#15085: *3 "/srv/www/myfolder/file/index.html" is not found (20: Not a directory), client: 192.168.1.35, server: , request: "GET /myfolder/file/ HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/myfolder/"
```

How can I change that ? 
I also tried with several browsers (FF, Safari) also cURL and wget .. still Error 404

**UPDATE 1**

```
 server {

            listen 80 default_server;
            rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
            gzip off;

       location /mirror {
                alias /srv/mirror;
                autoindex on;
        }
```

It is an Debian Mirror - if I comment the rewrite out, I get this Error:

```
 BZ2_bzread: /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/mirror.com_debian_dists_stretch_main_i18n_Translation-en.bz2 Read error (-5: DATA_ERROR_MAGIC)
```

If i comment that in Again, it can't find the Release file cause of the redirect ...

Comment: What is the exact URL you are requesting? What is the web root directory in nginx? Where exactly does the file exist in your file system?

Comment: all the information is in the Question. The webroot is /srv/www/.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I can see that your GET request is `request: "GET /myfolder/file/` !

If it is a file, the GET request should be without the backslash at the end.

The correct request will be.

`request: "GET /myfolder/file`

Comment: Yeah, and i found out why it get's redirected. I have this in my nginx.conf rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent; which makes sense - but i need to exclude the word "file". and don't get the regex correct to exclude the word "file".

Comment: Open a new question for this issue and include your nginx virtual host configuration in the question, then I can find a way to solve the issue.

Comment: I've updated the Question, if this is also okay ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the redirect to not end in a `/`, you should leave it off the redirect configuration.

In other words, change

```
        rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
```

to

```
        rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1 permanent;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this issue on my server. The cause of the error was a symlink.

I just encountered this (not very elucidating) error message on my server's nginx config:

```
"/path/to/index.html" is not found (20: Not a directory)
```

After some trial-and-error, I determined that the actual cause was that nginx couldn't access the site's document root because part of the path to the `root` included a symlink, but I had `disable_symlinks on;` set in my main `nginx.conf` file.

Commenting-out the `disable_symlinks on;` line or changing it to `disable_symlinks off;` fixes the issue.

See also:

- https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#disable_symlinks